# How to change view in Qml?

Tags: qt, qml

My program will display pictures in 3 ways: ListView, GridView and PathView. Program will have 3 buttons for each type and when i press button for ListView images are dispayed as list and so on... I can do this with Qml Loader:

```
Loader { id: pageLoader; anchors.fill: parent; source: "pics/PathLayout.qml"}
```

and then when i will press button, source will be changed. The problem is that it will download source again and again that is not good.
Another way is to locate views not in separate files, but in main.qml, set visible: false and using states change visible for true. Now problem is that i will instantiate all three views at the start even if i will not change view.
Can I somehow do this, so program starts with GrisView, for example, and it will download another view only if i press button and somehow remember this view so when will need it again, I will not download it again?

Answer (score 0):

You could combine both solutions.

You declare a common model, three loaders (one for each type of view) and three associated buttons. The first time a button is clicked, you active the loader (this way the view is loaded). The next time a button is clicked, you only active/deactivate the visible property of the loaded Component.

Comment: So it is kind normal practice for GUI when some of your parts are visible others are not and you just switching visible property to select which one to print?

Comment: It's a common practice in QtQuick/Qt. A lot of Component like [ListView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html) are working like this.

But you should also care about the memory usage and performance of your app. Check the usage of Loader, Repeater and Instanciator for heavy Component.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me why your images would be downloaded over and over again. The list of images (the actual data) is your model, not your view. That should only occur once. Depending on your needs, that can be done in either C++ or QML. The way you display that model (your view) has nothing to do with that. And there's a million different ways you could display the images. Here's another option:

```
StackLayout {
    currentIndex: 1

    ListView {
        model: imageList
    }
    GridView {
        model: imageList
    }
    PathView {
        model: imageList
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but one moment, when i switching views focus:true property doesn't work. How can i deal with it?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you saying keyboard focus is not working when switching between the different views? You could always try calling `forceActiveFocus()`.